# Ubuntu 12.04 VM goes dead unexpectedly

Tags: 12.04, vmware, virtualization

I'm not a super savvy super user, so I'm not sure what to look for.  I have a VM running 12.04.

It runs fine, and then just dies (no ping, no ssh).  When I log into VMwareSphere, I see the VM still 'UP', but the console gives me a response-less black screen. This lead me to believe that Ubuntu was going into some sort of sleep/hibernate state. I double checked the power settings and found nothing out of the ordinary, so now I'm stuck on how to fix the problem.

There are 5-7 (CentOS-5.8 & 6) machines running on the same server/VM setup with no problems at all.

Comment: I noticed this happened after installing VMWare tools.. regretting that now!

Comment: Still reproducible?

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked with it in almost a year and have no extra details.  I can close out the question unless it's beneficial for someone to stumble across it, or someone has an answer.